# Controlling time of QTimer?

Tags: c++, qt, testing, time

I'm considering rewriting some existing C code using C++ and Qt. In the C code `poll` is used to check for input from several sources, and each source has a timeout value and some specific behaviour tied to it. For instance

- after 5 minutes silence on `intput0` we assume the other side is dead and we try to re-establish contact
- we expect clients to connect to `socket0`
- once a client has connected to `socket0` a call to `accept` is made (`socket1`), a client gets one minute to make a request before `socket1` is closed down

This sort of thing isn't too difficult test, by using `LD_PRELOAD` and "hiding" the involved system functions (`poll`, `gettimeofday`) one can (somewhat) easily control passage of time and trigger timeouts.

Moving to Qt I was planning on wrapping the filedescriptors in instances of `QSocketNotifier` and connect the `activated(int)` signal to a suitable slot. That basically provides a Qt-flavoured `poll` -- except there are no timeouts!

For timeouts I'm looking at coupling a `QTimer` to each `QSocketNotifier`. My experimentation shows this to work, and be rather elegant. However, it's not pleasurable to test. I can't really have tests that sit and wait 5 minutes for a timeout.

How do I go about making the timeouts in this solution testable?

(Or maybe I'm just thinking about this the wrong way, and should do something completely different.)

Comment: can't you just have the timeout as a variable and you set it to a lower one before the unit tests?

Comment: I removed the word "unit" because it's not really "unit tests". I could reduce the timeout time, but that's not how I usually try to approach testing. I'd rather control the environment, in this case *time*, and leave the thing under test as it's intended to be. In this particular case, I also want to test timeouts in integration tests (we have several processes communicating), and changing timeout values have more implications then.

Comment: having a configurable timeout sounds though like a nice feature. I don't see how this can be done without waiting 5 minutes there. Especially with Qt. If you had your own framework for time measurement you could implement a feature in it to "set" the time 5 minutes ahead but I see this also creating problems when you want to test with multiple processes where they are so interdependent on timings. (+ AFAIK you cannot do this with Qt).

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/49062286/1662265

Answer (score 4):

I believe the question can be paraphrased as "how to mock `QTimer`?" The answer to this reworded question is "indirectly." You could write your main program with an abstraction over `QTimer`, which would then be mocked by the test code to emit signals based on test needs instead of based on time.

One particular way of approaching this could be for the test code to disconnect the slot from the `QTimer`'s signal, and connect its own signal in its place.

Comment: Yes, the standard OO approach would be inversion of control via dependency injection. That approach is also a bit of a pain in languages with nominal typing. I was really hoping that `QTimer` was testable in some other way.

Comment: @Magnus Decide what you want to test. Do you want to test your reaction to a signal? Then emit the signal from something else. Do you want to test your reaction to `QTimer`? Then you're stuck with `QTimer`.

Comment: Well, I want to test the reaction to the signal, but only the `QTimer` instance has its signal attached to the slot, so they are pretty much the same. Do note that I'm not talking about just "unit testing" (where "unit" is a class) here.

Comment: @Magnus Still, Qt's signals and slots can be connected/disconnected from outside the classes involved, so you should be able to just re-wire everything to mock timers for the test, perhaps without even having to modify the production code.

Comment: I mean having to wait 5 minutes seems to me like reasonable for integration tests. Just automate them and let them run regularly somewhere and get an email notification when things go wrong. So you won't have to "actively" wait. But it would have been nice if the Qt test framework would have provided some "time change" functionality

Comment: Angew, please give pointer on how it's done *from an outside process*.

Comment: Hayt, the reason for pursuing this is that the test of the C code took a few seconds to run and thus could be run on each checking. Having a test that increases the CI build time by 50% won't be popular. So that means I'd have to push a test from being done on every checkin to being run a few times a day (our scheduled longer integration tests).

Comment: @Magnus I guess then something like a "mocking interface" would be reasonable... Something like a minimal RPC server sitting in your program (only if compiled with some special flag) and one of the RPC methods could be used to reduce timeouts / virtually move forward the time. That in turn might be acchievable by implementing a custom timer class (maybe implemented by the means of QTimer) which is used throughout the project...